# Преобразование типизированного объекта в TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в `TypeScript` `obj` преобразовать в `newObj`?

```
 interface Range {
  date: string;
  size: number;
  temp: [{
    name: string | null;
    text: string | null
  } | []];
}


let obj: Range[] = [{
    "date": "2020-01-20",
    "size": 8,
    "temp": [{
        "name": "aaa",
        "text": "AAA",
      },
      {
        "name": "bbb",
        "text": "BBB",
      },
      {
        "name": "ccc",
        "text": "CCC",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "date": "2020-01-21",
    "size": 7,
    "temp": []
  }
];

let newObj = [{
    "date": "2020-01-20",
    "size": 8,
    "prop": true,
    "name": "aaa",
    "text": "AAA"
  },
  {
    "date": "2020-01-20",
    "size": 8,
    "prop": true,
    "name": "bbb",
    "text": "BBB"
  },
  {
    "date": "2020-01-20",
    "size": 8,
    "prop": true,
    "name": "ccc",
    "text": "CCC"
  },
  {
    "date": "2020-01-21",
    "size": 7,
    "prop": false,
    "name": null,
    "text": null
  }
];
```

Comment: obj объявлена как Range а присваиваешь ей массив - это ошибка https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=11&ssc=5&pln=11&pc=6#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEpxAcxQbwFDLIAmckAXMgM5hSiYDcBVwAXhBSAK4C2ARtI0KRuABwoBtfIUIg43dlRp1kAH2RcANhsHTIADzAVqtLKvWctTAL5nxAXTuMreFxohhkAe14ArCuiwUAF5kSSZCACISSAiKCIAmAAYkgFpEgEYUpIiAGnDkCMpWCFjkAA486QLhEVKwqqqI2XlSiLh23PzG-TBWgEEBzobkK0qGqWGC5pK43jmhyYie1oAhNYWq0a7kCeGmuRmChGONhqWIA1aAYRvTwmcqu2sx3YLow4TkxLTM+PTTwrFUoAdjGkRqdSe9zwjiAA

Comment: Исправила, спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[там песочница](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=74&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCRTiA5ig3gKGSOQBM5IAuZAZzClCwG5DjrgAvCKkAVwFsARtGbFkkPgAcqqcROYBffGACeElOkw4AMsFrIAvGgzYIAbQC6zfKEixE62QHkBAK2QFRIOHy406DZAAfZF4AG1CRYkgADzAqWnpsIJCecIUlVQcISQM0J1cLKwB6IuQAWjKAPmRAIRBABhBALhBrcGh4JCNNCAAhdxYiMko-RKY%20mg5fXkFhUYkoAHspZAE5udCITEiiLx9pfJdTAHJtiAPLUZi4vOyJZ32Di9P0kuRADhBAbhAX-GeVNQ6THsMjj4wDAAB4NCYADTIe7XA7VABkV0kt2QSNwyFmCyoy1W6xAyHkzB%206mMOC6Oj0hgh5MK%20C%20pVBFXpJL%20OAATGTupSwLkABRc6RcgCUBmqNO5ujA%20AQcxAei5nM6FKlQs6Sv%20PNyXLFowAglAMMoAHQweZ8AWdY2yaF8jHHaEXQmi-TVO2jTzeCCOiCxSEe4gDXxc41B-2iURsThUENR70BohYxbwULUeOieTIODUNndYXC%20my%20W8vjkejRdlwQ380v%20aJUTDKCwWYUNkBN8y60S18vGqAQEg8JB8vlVqDQgCO0OALrdY%20NEh41AAFnzjeue8BoqZgOZhZCx-vkC2WZlczyNeStYY%20aFVeepbPcyraDK5QrOheuS-LhKv8rr2QO8qUqUZNwrMc%20QTICpWNUsJEtExL0lWgC1EAt8DWXlBQfKlj1GDwI36chfAAInZAAGSiygogBGMpKNI8MiLGaNkAADmYojZCoUxCJY4hSOOUiqFIuBxKY6DRFIi4ROQUi9UUySBPkLiI34gT5OE0SBF05TNKIGTfTAOTSK6cz9KI1ToI0gShK9UyECcyzNKM2JTIAYS8lyM2g8xRms0RbMDEjRMo6i6IY2ifNYcYqAAdjU0QeOPfzfLON9ixCCAAHdUUMLl-01KVEJwAsi2oPFjVCOYsD5EBctuDCgA)

### разбираемся с типами

```
interface $range {
    date: string;
    size: number;
    temp: $temp;
}
type $rangeList = $range[];

interface $tempObj {
    name: string | null;
    text: string | null;
}
type $temp = $tempObj[];

// --> так
interface $rangeB {
    date: string;
    size: number;
    prop: boolean;
    name: $tempObj['name'];
    text: $tempObj['text'];
}
// или
// type $rangeB = Omit<$range, 'temp'> & $tempObj & { prop: boolean };
type $rangeBList = $rangeB[];
```

### пишем ф-ии преобразования

```
type $range2rangeBList = (range: $range) => $rangeBList
const range2rangeBList: $range2rangeBList = range =>
    Array.from(range.temp, ({ name, text }) => ({
        name, text,
        date: range.date,
        size: range.size,
        prop: false,
    } as $rangeB))

const matrix2arr = (matrix: any[][]): any[] =>
    matrix.reduce((arr, q, i) => (arr.push(...matrix[i]),arr), [])

type $rangeList2rangeBList = (list: $rangeList) => $rangeBList
const rangeList2rangeBList: $rangeList2rangeBList = list =>
    matrix2arr(
        list.map(range2rangeBList)
    )
```

### проверяем

```
let range: $rangeList = [
    {
        date: "2020-01-20",
        size: 8,
        temp: [{
            "name": "aaa",
            "text": "AAA",
        },
        {
            "name": "bbb",
            "text": "BBB",
        },
        {
            "name": "ccc",
            "text": "CCC",
        }
        ]
    },
    {
        date: "2020-01-21",
        size: 7,
        temp: []
    }
];

const newObj = rangeList2rangeBList(range)
console.log(newObj)
```

### запустить можно тут

```js
"use strict";
const range2rangeBList = range => Array.from(range.temp, ({ name, text }) => ({
    name, text,
    date: range.date,
    size: range.size,
    prop: false,
}));
const matrix2arr = (matrix) => matrix.reduce((arr, q, i) => (arr.push(...matrix[i]), arr), []);
const rangeList2rangeBList = list => matrix2arr(list.map(range2rangeBList));
let range = [
    {
        date: "2020-01-20",
        size: 8,
        temp: [{
                "name": "aaa",
                "text": "AAA",
            },
            {
                "name": "bbb",
                "text": "BBB",
            },
            {
                "name": "ccc",
                "text": "CCC",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        date: "2020-01-21",
        size: 7,
        temp: []
    }
];
const newObj = rangeList2rangeBList(range);
console.log(newObj);
```